# Ubuntu stuck at HP logo after trying to setup swapfile for hibernation

Tags: hibernate, ubuntu-20.04, swap-file

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which I installed dual boot to Windows. I wanted to add Hibernation as an option. So I installed pm utilities and tried `sudo pm-hibernate` It did not work. I read somewhere that the swap file should be equal to the size of my RAM. My RAM is 8 GB and my swap file was 1.4 GB (default). I hadn't tampered with anything earlier when I had installed Ubuntu.

Then after looking up, I followed [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/q/1285207). And I did everything exactly up until about 7 steps where it says to "reboot".

Steps include - doing swapoff -a, adding a # against a UUID in the existing swap file. Creating an 8GB swap file using `sudo fallocate -l 8G /swapfile`

`sudo mkswap /swapfile`

```
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile

sudo swapon /swapfile`
```

And then I hit reboot. Then it boots to get stuck at HP logo (Ubuntu at the bottom). I tried hard shud down and booting again. It again gets frozen at HP logo.

Did mess anything up? How do I go ahead and fix this?

Edit - I must mention that there were 3 UUID's in the file. I didnt know which one to add a # to. Then I looked up how search for my UUID of the swap file and found my UUID and then hashed only that one.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly did you add this hash?

It sounds like you may have edited fstab and commented out your root/boot partition?

Revert to the backup file you made before editing it, and run `grub-update` for good measure.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. I went to recovery mode and removed the # from the fstab that I had added in front of a UUID. And now it booted. And the swapfile says it's 8GB but it still shuts down, instead of hibernate. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: -What- says the swapfile is 8GB? The command `free -h` will show you what your system currently recognises. You -will- need a line in fstab like `/swapfile.swp    none    swap    sw    0   0` for it to be activated at boot. I'm not sure how ubuntu handles hibernation but `man pm-hibernate` should give you some light reading.